# Dealing with negative eigenvalues due to floating point errors

Tags: r, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

> After reading other answers and investigating, I understand my error is a floating point error. I have not seen any answers that provide a good solution, for my use case.

Context: Using the `matpower` function from the `sSDR` package, in r, to help me standardise my predictors `X` data.

My data, `X`, is shaped as follows (real data set has more rows and columns):

```
      Press_mm_hg RH_out Windspeed Visibility Tdewpoint      rv1      rv2
1       733.5     92  7.000000   63.00000       5.3      13.27543 13.27543
2       733.6     92  6.666667   59.16667       5.2      18.60619 18.60619
3       733.7     92  6.333333   55.33333       5.1      28.64267 28.64267
4       733.8     92  6.000000   51.50000       5.0      45.41039 45.41039
5       733.9     92  5.666667   47.66667       4.9      10.08410 10.08410
6       734.0     92  5.333333   43.83333       4.8      44.91948 44.91948
```

I would like to raise `var(X)` to the power of `-0.5`. I do this as follows (extracted code from `matpower` function from the `sSDR` package):

```
# options(scipen=999) helps you visualise the problem better.
X_var = var(X) # compute var of X.
X_var_sum = (var_X + t(var_X))/2 # Sum the result
tmp = eigen(X_var_sum) # Eigenvalue decomposition 

e_values <- tmp$values # Get the values
e_vectors <- tmp$vectors # Get the vectors

e_vectors %*% diag(e_values^alpha) %*% t(e_vectors) # Raise the matrix to the power.
```

**So what is the error?**

The error occurs during the eigenvalue decomposition. Something about the structure of my data results in negatives for the eigen values. For example,

```
> e_values
[1] 497.855846350015326606808230280876159667969
[2]  37.044927498529837350815796526148915290833
[3]   0.000000000000034235240904804834595748182
[4]   0.000000000000000006398983555805967132521
[5]   0.000000000000000000000000000000000385186
[6]  -0.000000000000000003469446977025200723022
[7]  -0.000000000000012918418921653726177566030
```

The has further implications for raising the eigenvalues to the power -0.5. As `e_values^alpha` has `NaN` values because of the negatives.

**Possible Solutions**

1. Setting negative eigen values to 0.

   - `0^(-0.5)` is infinity.
   - So not viable as future calculations rely on this.
2. Setting making the values positive. (my current solution)

   - As the numbers are so small, due to an error, `abs(e_values)` returns huge numbers down the line.
3. Setting the value to almost 0, but just above.

   - I think this will completely skew the data

**The Question**

Is there a better way to deal with this or perhaps a different eigenvalue decomposition algorithm, that is less prone to these errors?

**`X` data from `dput()`**

```
`structure(list(Press_mm_hg = c(733.5, 733.6, 733.7, 733.8, 733.9, 
734), RH_out = c(92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92), Windspeed = c(7, 6.66666666666667, 
6.33333333333333, 6, 5.66666666666667, 5.33333333333333), Visibility = c(63, 
59.1666666666667, 55.3333333333333, 51.5, 47.6666666666667, 43.8333333333333
), Tdewpoint = c(5.3, 5.2, 5.1, 5, 4.9, 4.8), rv1 = c(13.275433157105, 
18.6061949818395, 28.6426681675948, 45.4103894997388, 10.0840965518728, 
44.9194842483848), rv2 = c(13.275433157105, 18.6061949818395, 
28.6426681675948, 45.4103894997388, 10.0840965518728, 44.9194842483848
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get output by using a combination of `zapsmall` and perturbing by `.Machine$double.eps`, but I'd be cautious with the output.

```
e_vectors %*% diag((zapsmall(e_values)+.Machine$double.eps)^alpha) %*% t(e_vectors)
              [,1]          [,2]          [,3]          [,4]          [,5]
[1,]  6.706360e+07 -1.280137e-09  1.508856e+05  1.735184e+06  4.526567e+04
[2,] -1.280137e-09  6.710886e+07  2.793968e-09  5.913898e-08 -2.328306e-10
[3,]  1.508856e+05  2.793968e-09  6.660591e+07 -5.783946e+06 -1.508856e+05
[4,]  1.735184e+06  5.913898e-08 -5.783946e+06  5.934833e+05 -1.735184e+06
[5,]  4.526567e+04 -2.328306e-10 -1.508856e+05 -1.735184e+06  6.706360e+07
[6,] -3.874249e-04  5.444576e-09  1.291434e-03  1.485146e-02  3.874244e-04
[7,] -3.874249e-04 -5.029556e-09  1.291425e-03  1.485146e-02  3.874330e-04
              [,6]          [,7]
[1,] -3.874249e-04 -3.874249e-04
[2,]  5.444576e-09 -5.029556e-09
[3,]  1.291434e-03  1.291425e-03
[4,]  1.485146e-02  1.485146e-02
[5,]  3.874244e-04  3.874330e-04
[6,]  3.355443e+07 -3.355443e+07
[7,] -3.355443e+07  3.355443e+07
```

Comment: Thank you this is great. Could you help me understand some of the consequences of this method? So why to be cautious? As well as the advantages over just using `abs()` for the eigen values?

Comment: @GooJ The calculation might be sensitive to numerical instabilities, it might not be telling you what you think it is. You need to check it works as you expect.